# If I call function inside document ready it will not work, but if I call it on an event it works just fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a java script function `my_func()` that i would like to call upon page loads. Here is the strange behavior that I will get: If I call the function inside the document ready it will not work:

```
function my_func(){
//do something
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   my_func();   
});
```

but if I call it on an event it works just fine:

```
function my_func(){
//do something
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myId').click( function(){
       my_func();
    });   
});
```

does anybody have any idea? how can I call it inside the document ready directly?

Comment: What does this function do?

Comment: Where is `my_func` defined?

Comment: You're probably doing: `my_func = function() {...` instead of `function my_func() {...`. There's a difference.

Comment: no the function is not defined inside another function. please look at the edited question

Comment: @Amin: We really need to see the contents of the function, then; from what you're showing us, it should work just fine.

Comment: btw, how does it matter what does the function do when it runs fine inside the $().click event?!

Comment: @icktoofay, the function is not short, and I could not run it in jsfiddle since i used both Dojo and jQuery inside it.

Comment: @Amin: Well your problem lies somewhere in there. The probable cause is that you have two `ready` listeners (perhaps one from Dojo and one from jQuery) and the first one tries to call `my_func` when whatever it needs is not initialized, and the second one initializes it. I guess you could test this by trying `setTimeout(my_func, 0);`. If it starts working, that's your problem.

Comment: @icktoofay,I think i am getting close to the issue! my_func() does not return any value. it just make some changes to the existing tags in the page (also adding some tags). when i include it in the ready() i recieve the error that "undefined is not a function" where undefined is I believe the return value of the my_func(). can this be the problem? apparenty if i run it inside another function (here .click(), the return value of this function is actually a function and can be run inside the ready(function(...)) )Do you think that may be the issue?

Comment: @icktoofay, setTimeout() did not work :(

Comment: @Amin: "`undefined` is not a function" occurs in many circumstances. Try to figure out where it's getting `undefined`. A debugger helps.

Comment: @icktoofay, Thanks for your help. I got where the error comes from, I have the following line: 

var newBox = new dijit.form.TextBox();
but why the error will go away if i call this in a nested function?! it is just making me crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `dijit.form.TextBox` has not been loaded when the rest of the DOM has loaded. You'll need to change your `my_func` code to include a call to `require`:

```
function my_func() {
    require(['dijit/form/TextBox'], function(TextBox) {
        // ...
        var newBox = new TextBox();
        // ...
    });
}
```

You'll need to do this for every Dojo class. For example, if you also need `dijit.form.Button`:

```
function my_func() {
    require(['dijit/form/Button', 'dijit/form/TextBox'], function(Button, TextBox) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

It's a little unfortunate that it's this verbose, but that's the way it goes. More information about `require` is available in [Dojo's documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/loader/amd.html).

Comment: this actually solves it! :D thanks a lot. I thought it is enough if i put a require in the html header but it looks that was not enough! thanks again anyways...

Comment: @Amin: It used to be that you could just use `dojo.require` at the top and it would synchronously load any modules you needed, but that makes the page unresponsive, so in the newer versions it's been replaced with this asynchronous `require`, which, unfortunately, requires some changes to existing code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *not* putting a function inside `$(document).ready()`, see below:

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/whFNj/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   my_func();   
});

function my_func(){
$("#black").css("background", "black");
}
```

Instead, it may be your function is being created somewhere else in your code and it's not initialized by the time the dom is ready.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know a simple function like this works fine. I could not define the function outside the scope, since as I said, I can call it inside the $().click() and it will work just fine. My question is exactly this, what may be the case that I can not call this function inside the ready function while i can call it inside a function inside the ready function!!!